# Create a list where some members are the values of defined variables

Tags: list, tcl

I have declared a variable named "_numCols" and set to some integer value (i.e 10). I am trying to include this variable in a list named "arry_in" in following way:

```
set arry_in {-1 1 $_numCols $_numCols}
```

But when I display the value of "arry_in" at index 2 and 3, it shows $_numCols instead of 10. Shouldn't $ sign give me the value of _numCols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces prevent substitution of the content in between them (it's similar to single quotes in shell languages).

Try one of these instead:

```
set arry_in [list -1 1 $_numCols $_numCols]
set arry_in "-1 1 $_numCols $_numCols"
```

Double quotes will do in many situations, but will collapse list content which is substituted into the string:

```
% set x [list foo [list bar baz]]
foo {bar baz}
```

but

```
% set x "foo [list bar baz]"
foo bar baz
```

Sometimes you want one, sometimes the other.

Documentation:
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)